# Sum of a variable number of Big O's terms

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Let $k=o(n)$, let $n\to \infty$. I am interested in the asymptotic behaviour of
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k \log\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right).
$$
By using the Taylor series of $\log$ I obtain
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k \log\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right) = \sum_{i=0}^k -\frac{i}{n} + O\left(\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2\right) = \frac{-k(k+1)}{2n} + O\left(\frac{k^3}{n^2}\right)
$$

Manipulation with Big O seems too hand-wavy, and I'm not sure if this is correct.
I have $k$ and $n$ that both go to $\infty$, the first big O is based around $n$, but there is still the summation up to $k$ outside.

Does this make sense? Is it correct?
What if $k=o(\sqrt{n})$ or $k=o(n^{\frac{2}{3}})$, does that change anything?

Answer (score 2):

Your work is correct, but it seems that it's not justified fully. Let's rewrite your first step (expansion of the Taylor series):
$$\sum_{i=0}^k\log\Big(1-\frac{i}{n}\Big)=-\sum_{i=0}^k\sum_{t=1}^\infty\frac{1}{t}\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^t=-\sum_{i=0}^k\bigg(\frac{i}{n}+\sum_{t=2}^\infty\frac{1}{t}\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^t\bigg).$$
Now you are right with intruducing the big-O element, but the furthest you can go is this:
$$-\sum_{i=0}^k\bigg(\frac{i}{n}+\mathcal{O}\bigg(\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^2\bigg)\bigg)=-\frac{k(k+1)}{2n}-\sum_{i=0}^k\mathcal{O}\bigg(\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^2\bigg).$$
You can't just swap the sum and the big-O. For that you need a *uniform bound*. Every big-O has some linear bound and here you have arbitrarily many big-O's. You need to give them a common bound. You can get just that with the next inequality:
$$0<\sum_{t=2}^\infty\frac{1}{t}\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^t<\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^2\Rightarrow0<\sum_{i=0}^k\bigg(\sum_{t=2}^\infty\frac{1}{t}\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^t\bigg)<\sum_{i=0}^k\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^2<\frac{k^3}{n^2}.$$
Now you can directly apply this to the first step:
$$-\frac{k(k+1)}{2n}-\frac{k^3}{n^2}<\sum_{i=0}^k\log\Big(1-\frac{i}{n}\Big)<-\frac{k(k+1)}{2n}.$$
And just now you can conclude your result:
$$\sum_{i=0}^k\log\Big(1-\frac{i}{n}\Big)=-\frac{k(k+1)}{2n}+\mathcal{O}\bigg(\frac{k^3}{n^2}\bigg).$$
You could go even further with:
$$\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^2<\sum_{t=2}^\infty\frac{1}{t}\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^t<\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^2\Rightarrow\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^k\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^2<\sum_{i=0}^k\bigg(\sum_{t=2}^\infty\frac{1}{t}\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^t\bigg)<\sum_{i=0}^k\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^2$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{1}{3}\frac{k^3}{n^2}<\sum_{i=0}^k\bigg(\sum_{t=2}^\infty\frac{1}{t}\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^t\bigg)<\frac{k^3}{n^2},$$
and derive a tighter bound:
$$\sum_{i=0}^k\log\Big(1-\frac{i}{n}\Big)=-\frac{k(k+1)}{2n}+\mathcal{\Theta}\bigg(\frac{k^3}{n^2}\bigg).$$

Comment: Could you give me a counterexample - where the "put the sum inside the big O" wouldn't work due to lack of a uniform bound?

Comment: @Kolja Yes, but it would be a little hard to give it in form of your problem, it's too specific. Also, big O of something that has both $i$ and $n$ requires a little more formalization about what we mean by it - what is a constant there and what is not... Big O is too hand-wavy, indeed. To clear that first, the solution I gave you essentially has only one parameter in big-O: that is $n$. Then $k$ is just a function of $n$ so it is a dependent variable. In your writings however $i$ and $n$ are not dependent. Your big-O assumes that $\frac{i}{n}$ tends to 0 as a whole.

Comment: It's hard to decide how much my example should resemble your solution because if I change it too much it won't seem relatable and if I copy many details it won't be a counter-example since your writings are correct... Let me think about a good example and then I'll add it to the answer

Comment: Thank you, I'd appreciate a counterexample. Because how I see it is that either I shouldn't be allowed to use a big O inside the sum since the sum depends on $n$, or if I am allowed to use a big O inside the sum, I should then be allowed to swap the sum with the big O. Of course I guess I could write out all the definitions and figure it out, but the point of the big O notation is not to do that, but keep things simple. If I have to develop the whole Taylor series of $\log$, there's no point in using big O.

Comment: I'll come back to think about it tomorrow, but for now maybe the most subtle change that would make the swapping illegal is to parametrize the function in the sum. This $\log$ is the same across the sum, make it not the same and there will be plenty of counter-examples. I think this correlates the best with the validity of the swap and that it fits the context the best, but I'll take a nicer look at it tomorrow.